# Problems about orthogonal projection

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

I'm now encountering a problem about orthogonal projection and change of basis. 
I'm asked to find a transformation matrix for the linear transformation $proj_{W}(x)$ and $proj_{W^{\perp}}(x)$, where W is a space spanned by the set of vectors ${[1,2,3,-4]^{T}, [2,3,-4,1]^{T}, [2,-5,8,-3]^{T}, [5,26,-9,-12]^{T}, [3,-4,1,2]^{T}}$ and x is the vector $[1,0,-3,-7]^{T}$. 
I'm required to use the method changing the basis of vectors, that is 
$$ [T(u)]_{\beta v} = [T]_{\beta u \beta v}[u]_{\beta u} $$
I know that to solve this question, I first need to reduce it to the rref, which is 
$$ 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 5 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & -2 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
 $$, 
which means that the span space W's basis is the set 
$$ {[1,0,0,0]^{T}, [0,1,0,0]^{T}, [0,0,1,0]^{T}} $$, then I can find the [T] for transformation matrix is 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Then the problem comes, using this method, I will find the answer to be $[1,0 ,-3]^{T}$, which is not equal to the answer got by directly computing the orthogonal projection, which is $[1,0,-3,0]^{T}$. I'm really confused, could you figure out the problems here? Thanks!

Comment: No. From your rref computation, you just know that the first three vectors $[1,2,3,-4]^T, [2,3,-4,1]^T, [2, -5,8,-3]^T$ is a basis for $W$. Now from Gram-schmidt, you can produce an orthogonal basis that also spans $W$, then you can compute $proj_W(x)$. If you are still stuck, I shall expand this to an answer.

Comment: Thanks bro, I get it! Now I found this problem really complicated to calculate:)

Comment: Yeah. Complicated it is. Good luck!

Comment: Hint: Since you’ve determined that $\dim W=3$, compute the matrix for the projection onto $W^\perp$ first. The matrix of the projection onto $W$ can be derived from it very simply, and this way is a *lot* less work.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I guess that then I can get the $dim(W^{\perp})$ = 1, so it's easier, but how can I get back to the W case?

Comment: @AsianDuckKing $proj_W=id-proj_{W^\perp}$, i.e., orthogonal projection onto the complement of a space is the same as orthogonal rejection from that space.